# Bringing elevation feature from point shape layer to line shape layer in attribute table using QGIS

Tags: qgis, snapping, vector-layer

I have two shapefiles. One point shapefile containing Levee station ID and their x,y and elevation/z values in meters. z values field name is 'StationE'. Another polyline shapefile where I don't have any x,y,z values. All the points overlap with the line shapes.   I want to bring the x,y,z attributes from the point shapefile to the polyline shapefile. I have tried join attributes by location with no luck and also tried snapping the points to the line layer but it can't create the layer. Don't know if it's due to SAGA version or problem in my shapefiles.
This is the point shapefile.

[image: Point Shapefile]

Here are my files in this link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JSaiSTwJcjVZjOdg4DszbuX4uOfZBsdC/view?usp=sharing

This is the line shapefile.
[image: Line Shapefile]

Comment: Have you tried `join attributes by nearest`?

Comment: yes, I have also tried join `attributes by nearest`. The point layer has 5106 stations/points columns in the attribute table but the line layer has only 60 attributes because it's only few polylines. Somehow, during joinging only line start end length are coming not the x,y, StationE/z/elevation of the stations points. Thanks much.

Comment: I have just added the screenshots. What I need is to get the elevation of the stations over the line. I am modeling a dam on the Mississippi. The line shapes are Levees on the riverbanks to protect the city. I need the elevation of the Levees on the lines so that I can measure if overtoping (of water) can happen during a flood. Thanks.

Comment: the attribute named `stationE` are z values which are elevations of those points/stations on top of the levees.